# Google Cloud dataflow : How to initialize Hikari connection pool only once per worker (singleton)?

Tags: hibernate, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, hikaricp

Hibernate Utils is creating the session factory along with Hikari configuration.
Currently we are doing inside @Setup method of ParDo, but it opens way too many connections. So is there any good example to initialize connection pool per worker ?

Comment: What is the usecase for connecting to Hikari?

Comment: So just to give an overview there are 5 pipelines consuming from individual pubsub topics and post transformation writing to Postgres which is shared. Using hibernate as orm backed up by hikaricp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `@Setup` method inside `DoFn` to create a database connection keep in mind that Apache Beam would create connection pool per worker instance thread. This might result in a lot of database connections depending on the number of workers that spin up.

You can use a Singleton class inside a ParDo to create your connection pool and control the number of connections per worker. You can take a look here for a sample implementation

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/beam-issues/201905.mbox/%3CJIRA.13231789.1557156230000.210182.1557222420198@Atlassian.JIRA%3E

Comment: Yes , this was the correct solution. Singleton 